# Capture video from iPhone camera with overlay view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocos3d

I'm creating an augmented reality app which overlays a 3D logo on the iPhone's video camera view using cocos3d.

I need to record the video with the logo overlay and write this to a file.

What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: sooo.... what is the question?

Comment: How to record video from iphone camera with overlay?

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify this project from apple: [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AVCam/Listings/Classes_AVCamViewController_m.html). Add your logoimage in the viewDidLoad method of AVCamViewController. You'll need to clean the XIB from everything but the view.

Comment: it is not i am want, a alredy can preview an logo that overlaying camera view, now i want capture video file with overlayed logo.